# Directly access methods from another Class

Tags: java, class, methods

I want to be able to use a method from another class directly.

```
import package.dialog;

public class Class1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        dialog.dialog("This is a dialog");
    }
}


import javax.swing.JOptionPane
public class dialog {
    public static void dialog(String message) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
    }

}
```

This code works excactly as it's supposed to, but as you can see I'm using *dialog.dialog()*. I was wondering wether there is a way to use just use *dialog()* directly?

Comment: Even dialog.dialog should not work, your method is not `static`. But you can't.

Comment: Your `dialog`  method is not `static`, this code shouldn't work . Also, a `dialog` method from a `dialog` class inside a `dialog` package is very misleading .

Comment: No, you can not use the `dialog()` method directly. Because without mentioning or pointing it to the proper class, how the compiler is supposed to know that which `dialog()` method it should call?

Comment: *"This code works excactly as it's supposed to"* - This code produces a compiler error.  If that's the intended result then, yes, you can achieve the same result by using `dialog()` directly.

Comment: Because all methods in java must have class binding. So you cannot define a method without a class. You havn't C++ like global methods.

Comment: You can use a Lambda and pass it around. But with the sample you provided, you need to buck up a bit to reach there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your example doesn't compile because you cannot name your package "package". "package" is a Java keyword and not allowed to use as an identifier.

So we call it "mypackage". And according to Java conventions you should name classes with first letter uppercase. So I will use `Dialog` instead of `dialog` for the class name in my example below.

Then you can use a static import to call the method `dialog()` without prefix.

```
import static mypackage.Dialog.*;

public class Class1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    dialog("This is dialog");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't possible. Consider the following situation:

```
import package.dialog;

public class Class1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Omit the class and call the dialog method "directly"
        dialog("This is a dialog");
    }
}


import javax.swing.JOptionPane
public class dialog {
    public static void dialog(String message) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
    }

}

public class SomeOtherClass {
    public static void dialog(String message) {
        // Perform some action
    }
}
```

How would the compiler know which one you intended to call - the `dialog` method in the `dialog` class, or the `dialog` method in `SomeOtherClass`?

Programming languages are generally very carefully designed to avoid permitting this kind of ambiguity.

One notorious example of poor design (and the potential difficulty with doing what you suggest) is the [diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) in C++ and other languages with multiple inheritance, which is an ambiguity that results from something very similar to what you're proposing. In fact, that's one of the major reasons that C# and Java banned multiple inheritance. Point being that this is really not something you'd like languages to have.

Ultimately, that would make code more difficult to read and potentially ambiguous just to save a little typing. Remember that, for readability, it's always better to be as explicit as possible about your intent.